# How to add user in VSTS to the "Team Foundation Service Accounts" Group?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to migrate/transfer some workitems from a tfs  on premise server to a VSTS project.

Therefore the user who executes the TFS Integration tool must be a member of the VSTS "Team Foundation Service Accounts" group. How can be added my user to this group in VSTS? The add button is disabled. My user is a member of project collection admins.

At tfs on premise this was done with the command console using the "tfssecurity.exe" command. But now on VSTS?

I would be very grateful for any help

Comment: You can't add user to Team Foundation Service Accounts group directly on VSTS, With project collection admin, you can migrate work items through TFS Integration tool. What's the problem of you?  Note: Use of these integration tools with TFS 2013 and 2015 may cause errors. TFS Integration Tools will not be supported past May 31, 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Project Collection Administrator permission, you can migrate work items to VSTS through Integration tool. Also, you can’t add user to Team Foundation Service account group of VSTS.

For on-premises TFS, you need to add account to your Team Foundation Service account.

You can migrate work items through [OpsHub](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2) tool. The TFS Integration Tools were designed to work with Team Foundation Server 2012 and earlier. Use of these integration tools with TFS 2013 and 2015 may cause errors. TFS Integration Tools will not be supported past May 31, 2016.

Comment: But i get an exception on starting migration with TFS Integration Tools as follows: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Migration.Tfs2010WitAdapter.PermissionException: _TFS WIT bypass-rule submission is enabled. However, the migration service account 'my user account' is not in the Service Accounts Group on server 'https://xxx.myslmarketplace.com/xxx/nvs'_  I get this exception for target and source server. About OpsHub: for OpsHub Migrator Free Edition is my project to big. The tool does not allow to migrate.

Comment: @mercedakias You get that exception for target and source server. Did you add that user to your on premise TFS service account group? For VSTS, does the user can create or modify work items?

Comment: i added the user who executes the TFS Integration Tool to the TFS service account group of the source TFS. Now it works! There was no need to do something on VSTS. Workitems migrated successful. Thank u very much.

Comment: @mercedakias Since your issue has been solved, you can mark it as answer.